# How do I keep a spawned process alive in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, haskell-stack

I'm trying to set up a "bridge" between my Haskell code and an interactive command-line process. More specifically, I'm trying to run an [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/) REPL and send/receive through stdin/stdout. I wasn't sure exactly which library to use for this, but I went with [`typed-process`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.17/typed-process-0.2.3.0/System-Process-Typed.html#v:inherit).

**The issue I have is that my Haskell program finishes (or quits) while the REPL process is still running. How do I avoid this?**

Also, another problem is that the REPL process isn't getting any input from the stdin handle.

*My current code looks like this:*

```
run :: Document -> IO (Result () Text)
run (Document moduleName tests) =  do
    let config = createConfig

    p <- startProcess config

    hSetBuffering (getStdin p) NoBuffering
    hSetBuffering (getStdout p) NoBuffering

    Data.Text.IO.hPutStr (getStdin p) "True\n"
    Data.Text.IO.hGetChunk (getStdout p) >>= print

    _ <- waitExitCode p

    return (Ok ())


{-| Config for process.
-}
createConfig =
    shell "elm repl"
        |> setStdin createPipe
        |> setStdout createPipe
        |> setStderr closed
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, it seems that `stopProcess` forces the process to stop (it sends SIGTERM on unix).  This is because the docs state that it calls `terminateProcess`, and then waits.

We only want to wait without terminating the process. I would try `waitExitCode` or similar functions, instead.

Comment: Didn't mean to have `stopProcess` in my code, my bad. But yes, thanks, `waitExitCode` seems to help. It still exits after 30 seconds though.